# Using WebRTC to send an iOS devices’ screen capture using ReplayKit

Tags: ios, webrtc, screensharing, replaykit, apprtc

We would like to use WebRTC to send an iOS devices’ screen capture using ReplayKit.
The ReplayKit has a processSampleBuffer callback which gives CMSampleBuffer.

But here is where we are stuck, we can’t seem to get the CMSampleBuffer to be sent to the connected peer.
We have tried to create pixelBuffer from the sampleBuffer, and then create RTCVideoFrame.

we also extracted the RTCVideoSource from RTCPeerConnectionFactory and then used an RTCVideoCapturer and stream it to the localVideoSource.

Any idea what we are doing wrong?

```
var peerConnectionFactory: RTCPeerConnectionFactory?

override func processSampleBuffer(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, with sampleBufferType: RPSampleBufferType) {
 switch sampleBufferType {
           case RPSampleBufferType.video:

        // create the CVPixelBuffer
        let pixelBuffer:CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!;

        // create the RTCVideoFrame
        var videoFrame:RTCVideoFrame?;
        let timestamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
        videoFrame = RTCVideoFrame(pixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, rotation: RTCVideoRotation._0, timeStampNs: Int64(timestamp))

        // connect the video frames to the WebRTC
        let localVideoSource = self.peerConnectionFactory!.videoSource()
        let videoCapturer = RTCVideoCapturer()
        localVideoSource.capturer(videoCapturer, didCapture: videoFrame!)

        let videoTrack : RTCVideoTrack =   self.peerConnectionFactory!.videoTrack(with: localVideoSource, trackId: "100”)

        let mediaStream: RTCMediaStream = (self.peerConnectionFactory?.mediaStream(withStreamId: “1"))!
        mediaStream.addVideoTrack(videoTrack)
        self.newPeerConnection!.add(mediaStream)

        break
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution so far

Answer (score 5):

This is a great idea to implement you just have to render the **RTCVideoFrame** in the method that you have used in the snippet, and all the other object will initialize outsize the method, best way. for better understanding, I am giving you a snippet.

```
    var peerConnectionFactory: RTCPeerConnectionFactory?
    var localVideoSource: RTCVideoSource?
    var videoCapturer: RTCVideoCapturer?
    func setupVideoCapturer(){
          // localVideoSource and videoCapturer will use 
            localVideoSource = self.peerConnectionFactory!.videoSource() 
            videoCapturer = RTCVideoCapturer()
    //      localVideoSource.capturer(videoCapturer, didCapture: videoFrame!)
    
            let videoTrack : RTCVideoTrack =   self.peerConnectionFactory!.videoTrack(with: localVideoSource, trackId: "100")
    
            let mediaStream: RTCMediaStream = (self.peerConnectionFactory?.mediaStream(withStreamId: "1"))!
            mediaStream.addVideoTrack(videoTrack)
            self.newPeerConnection!.add(mediaStream)
        }


 override func processSampleBuffer(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, with sampleBufferType: RPSampleBufferType) {
     switch sampleBufferType {
               case RPSampleBufferType.video:
    
            // create the CVPixelBuffer
            let pixelBuffer:CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!;
    
            // create the RTCVideoFrame
            var videoFrame:RTCVideoFrame?;
            let timestamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
            videoFrame = RTCVideoFrame(pixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, rotation: RTCVideoRotation._0, timeStampNs: Int64(timestamp))
            // connect the video frames to the WebRTC
            localVideoSource.capturer(videoCapturer, didCapture: videoFrame!)
    
            break
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: What about the audio? RTCVideoTrack is only for video samples. Can anyone help me with audio snippet?

Comment: I tried, but as I check we can not do it with the existing framework. we can achieve this by customizing the SDK with source code. I did it with this way.

Comment: Can you please guide me with steps?If you could just share webrtc.framework & a snippet like above for audio that would be great help! May be answer my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54470143/send-replay-kit-audio-samplesnot-microphone-over-webrtc

Comment: Hi Sumit, can you please respond with steps if possible?

Comment: I tried the same way but I did not receive the video on the web. Can you please share your approach @sumitmeena  @replies? Many thanks

Comment: hi @Aboulfouz, you are not able to receive video in web or any remote device ??
you can check it on your local view if the video is working on local view than it will work in the remote.

Comment: HI @sumitmeena, Many thanks for answering I did not get the video on the web, The web page receives ontrack event but never shows the video :( .

Comment: Hi @user2801184 I can try but whenever I get time.

Comment: Hi @Aboulfouz can you share the snippet so that I can check it.

Comment: Hi @sumitmeena: I can work with you if you can guide me. If not I will wait for your response.@aboulfouz: If you run this https://github.com/Mobcrush/ReplayKitDemo with apprtc latest demo app from google. It did work for me.

Comment: sure I am looking forward for this.

Comment: Hi @sumitmeena, I used the same exact code above and to create the peerConnect
self.newPeerConnection = self.peerConnectionFactory?.peerConnection(with: rtcConfig, constraints: RTCMediaConstraints(mandatoryConstraints: ["OfferToRecieveVideo":"true"], optionalConstraints: nil), delegate: self)

Comment: have you check webrtc internal in chrome ?

Comment: I added the track id with 100 but in chrome when I inspected the stream object it contains a track with auto generated id not the 100, Could this cause the problem?
@sumitmeena many thanks for your time

Comment: getting these type of error when rendering above snippet to view in localView 
            Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFType width]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2829c6300'

Comment: Hi @sumitmeena The problem was with the timestamp. When I changed the timestamp to let ctm = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer) ctm.value. It worked but the video freezes after 10 secs :( did you encounter the same issue?

Comment: @sumitmeena@Aboulfouz.. iam getting buffers when transferring from iOS to  android but not from iOS to  iOS through WebRTC…..is there any problem with codec if yes how can I change the configuration ….Can you please help me out

Comment: @sumitmeena@Aboulfouz: Hey Guys 
 I am getting error with latest webrtc libraries Can you please help and answer my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61190672/unable-to-screencast-to-apprtc-using-replay-kit-over-webrtc