# Send Replay Kit Audio samples(not Microphone) Over Webrtc

Tags: ios, webrtc, screensharing, replaykit, apprtc

I am able to send Replaykit video samples to the remote peer but with no Audio. What to use instead of RTCVideoFrame? Is there a way I can send a Audio Video data together?

Below is the snippet:

```
 var peerConnectionFactory: RTCPeerConnectionFactory?
        var localVideoSource: RTCVideoSource?
        var videoCapturer: RTCVideoCapturer?
        func setupVideoCapturer(){
                // localVideoSource and videoCapturer will use 
                localVideoSource = self.peerConnectionFactory!.videoSource() 
                videoCapturer = RTCVideoCapturer()
                localVideoSource.capturer(videoCapturer, didCapture: videoFrame!)

                let videoTrack : RTCVideoTrack =   self.peerConnectionFactory!.videoTrack(with: localVideoSource, trackId: "100”)

                let mediaStream: RTCMediaStream = (self.peerConnectionFactory?.mediaStream(withStreamId: “1"))!
                mediaStream.addVideoTrack(videoTrack)
                self.newPeerConnection!.add(mediaStream)
            }


     override func processSampleBuffer(_ sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, with sampleBufferType: RPSampleBufferType) {
         switch sampleBufferType {
                   case RPSampleBufferType.video:

                // create the CVPixelBuffer
                let pixelBuffer:CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!;

                // create the RTCVideoFrame
                var videoFrame:RTCVideoFrame?;
                let timestamp = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
                videoFrame = RTCVideoFrame(pixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, rotation: RTCVideoRotation._0, timeStampNs: Int64(timestamp))
                // connect the video frames to the WebRTC
                localVideoSource.capturer(videoCapturer, didCapture: videoFrame!)

                break
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi @user2801184, Did you manage to receive video streaming using the code above? In my case I could not :(

Comment: Hi @Aboulfouz I just used above code for sending the RTCVideoFrame to another peer. Please refer to apprtc latest demo and use broadcast app like mobcrush. Not sure what is wrong with your code. can you post the code?

Comment: Hi @user2801184 The problem was with the timestamp. When I changed the timestamp to  let ctm = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer) ctm.value. It worked but the video freezes after 10 secs :(

Comment: @Aboulfouz: yes I encounter same issue where video freezes at specific sample using the ipad

Comment: can you please share how did you solve it?

Comment: I am still encountering same issue. can you ask your question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50267456/using-webrtc-to-send-an-ios-devices-screen-capture-using-replaykit/50953458?noredirect=1#comment96031230_50953458

Comment: I solved the issue by updating to the newest GoogleWebRTC library and use the following command:
localVideoSource?.adaptOutputFormat(toWidth: 768, height: 1024, fps: 10)

Comment: @Aboulfouz: Can you share the latest webrtc framework files? what version of webrtc libraries are you using?

Comment: GoogleWebRTC (1.1.26791), You can use Pod installation to get this version

Comment: Thanks, will try that!

Comment: That is not working anymore :(

Comment: @user2801184 Did you have any solution for audio?? Please share with me.

Comment: @ParthPatel: Sorry, I don't think there is solution for audio. Did you get video working? Can you share the solution?

Comment: @user2801184 For me, Video share is working now for me. I used your code for this.

Comment: @ParthPatel: Can you please share the libWebRTC-arm64

Comment: @user2801184 Sorry, I can't share lib file it is not with me but I can give you how you can do this.

Comment: @user2801184 You can download opensource code from here chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc

Comment: @ParthPatel: Thank you for the link. Can you please provide steps to create one after getting the source?

Comment: @user2801184 This is too long process not able to explain and I don't know about it. I know only one thing you have to make audio function to pass your audio stream.

Comment: @ParthPatel: Please share the audio function if possible.

Comment: @ParthPatel@Aboulfouz: Hey Guys 
 I am getting error with latest webrtc libraries Can you please help and answer my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61190672/unable-to-screencast-to-apprtc-using-replay-kit-over-webrtc