# WebRTC with ReplyKit swift Video Freezes after 10 seconds

Tags: swift, webrtc, replaykit

I have an iOS app which uses ReplayKit broadcast extension to share the screen with WebRTC Web Client the video starts and runs for 10 seconds then it freezes with the last frame.

I used the code posted in the question below 
[Using WebRTC to send an iOS devices’ screen capture using ReplayKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50267456/using-webrtc-to-send-an-ios-devices-screen-capture-using-replaykit/50953458?noredirect=1#comment96046635_50953458) Thanks for "sumit meena"

But the timestamp did not work I had to change it with

```
let ctm = CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(sampleBuffer)
let timestamps = ctm.value
```

Any advice?

Comment: Did you make any headway on this? I dropped the frame rate to 2 per sec, it ran fine for 2 minutes but again froze.

Comment: Try to reduce the frame size on the repeater

Comment: Yes, it has to do something with framesize and fps. I played around with both and got it working to some extent which is okay-ish for me at this point.